# select column names having custom string

Tags: r

I want to select column names having Q and have number only like Q12, Q45, Q99, Q121 etc. also the column should have numeric data .

```
i have tried 
select(matches("[[:digit:]]"))

also tried 
select(starts_with(paste("Q",0:100, sep = "")))


``
```

Comment: `mydata %>% select(matches("Q[0-9]+") & where(is.numeric))`?

Comment: also the selected  column should have numeric data

Comment: yes, my comment includes that (reload in case you don't see `where(is.numeric)` in it)

Comment: but somewhere column also have Q45.sale , Q22_book, that i want to disselect

Comment: okay, `matches("^Q[0-9]+$")`?

Comment: r2evans looks more flexible, but if we know all the indexes in "Q[digits]" variables, we can use `num_range`, as in `select(num_range(prefix = "Q", range = c(21, 45, 99, 121))`